Anyone know what this cartoon train whistle is from?
A friend asked me about this picture and it looks SO familiar, but nothing I search for turns out to be it.
My memory of it, which may be unreliable, includes that there is someone pulling the whistle cord over and over, seeing that the vehicle (may or may not be a train) is advancing toward some danger. The whistle sees the danger, too, hence its expression. I can remember the lever on the neck of the whistle going up and down, and I can sort of remember the face of the whistle turning red as it becomes exhausted from blowing so much, but I can't tell if I'm remembering that from the same scene/show or from some other scene/show, or even if all these memories are simply an amalgamation of every cartoon suspense vehicle crash I've ever seen.


I've got no evidence to back this up, so I'm only commenting.  I think it's from Who Framed Roger Rabbit?.  I've not been able to find any corresponding proof as it's not a main character in that, but fits the style

It's from Walt Disney's Disneyland, Season 4, Episode 8 ("Adventures in Fantasy"). See the relevant reddit thread here. While the show featured bits from existing films, some animations were created specifically for TV; this one was of a Father Whistle and a Son Whistle. Here's a still from the episode:


Could you please provide source material or anymore information supporting it

Season 4 (with the mentioned episode) was called 'Disneyland episodes' according to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walt_Disney_anthology_television_series#Season_4_.281957-1958.29

Added some details. Techincally, this is the correct answer.

Melody time little toot, the whistle on the boat. It has evolved over the years but that is it




I don't think I agree. It appears Little Toot from Melody Time was based on the Little Toot children's books. And even through the books and only other movie, the whistle has only one "leg", no eyes, and the style is different.
